# Actionview::Template::Error in Heroku, but not localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an app that works fine on `localhost` but when I deploy to Heroku one of my model `index` pages displays an error.  The model in question is `workouts#index` and here are my Heroku logs displaying the error:

```
2016-06-06T19:13:56.408259+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/workouts" for 70.181.88.50 at 2016-06-06 19:13:56 +0000
2016-06-06T19:13:56.412002+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by WorkoutsController#index as HTML
2016-06-06T19:13:56.417923+00:00 app[web.1]:   Workout Load (4.8ms)  SELECT  "workouts".* FROM "workouts"  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
2016-06-06T19:13:56.438116+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-06T19:13:56.438123+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"workouts", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]):
2016-06-06T19:13:56.438124+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:   <%# if current_user != nil && current_user.admin? %>
2016-06-06T19:13:56.438125+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:     <h3 class="cta"><%= link_to 'Create a New Workout', new_workout_path %></h2>
2016-06-06T19:13:56.438126+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:   <%# else %>
2016-06-06T19:13:56.425828+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered workouts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.1ms)
2016-06-06T19:13:56.434933+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 22ms (ActiveRecord: 4.8ms)
2016-06-06T19:13:56.438127+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:     <h3 class="cta"><%= link_to 'Try the Most Recent Workout', workout_path(@most_recent_workout) %></h3>
2016-06-06T19:13:56.269357+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"workouts", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]):
2016-06-06T19:13:56.269358+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:   <%# if current_user != nil && current_user.admin? %>
2016-06-06T19:13:56.269360+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:     <h3 class="cta"><%= link_to 'Create a New Workout', new_workout_path %></h2>
2016-06-06T19:13:56.269360+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:   <%# else %>
2016-06-06T19:13:56.269362+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:     <h3 class="cta"><%= link_to 'Try the Most Recent Workout', workout_path(@most_recent_workout) %></h3>
2016-06-06T19:13:56.269362+00:00 app[web.1]:     16:   <%# end %>
2016-06-06T19:13:56.438128+00:00 app[web.1]:     16:   <%# end %>
2016-06-06T19:13:56.438129+00:00 app[web.1]:     17: </div>
2016-06-06T19:13:56.438129+00:00 app[web.1]:     18: 
2016-06-06T19:13:56.438130+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/workouts/index.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_workouts_index_html_erb___1546867497932887864_70318699165220'
2016-06-06T19:13:56.438131+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-06T19:13:56.438131+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-06T19:13:56.450459+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/workouts" host=radiant-island-49597.herokuapp.com request_id=f67b8f74-822c-47d4-84fa-6b95536e629d fwd="70.181.88.50" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=65ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

Here is the `workouts_controller` file:

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @workouts = Workout.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @most_recent_workout = Workout.order("created_at").last
  end

  def show
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @exercise = Exercise.new
    @report = Report.new
  end

  def new
    @workout = Workout.new
    @workout.user_id = current_user
  end

  def create
    @workout = Workout.new(workout_params)
    @workout.user = current_user

    if @workout.save
      flash[:notice] = "Workout was saved successfully."
      redirect_to @workout
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error creating workout. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @workout.user_id = current_user
  end

  def update
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])

    @workout.name = params[:workout][:name]
    @workout.workout_type = params[:workout][:workout_type]
    @workout.teaser = params[:workout][:teaser]
    @workout.description = params[:workout][:description]
    @workout.video = params[:workout][:video]
    @workout.difficulty = params[:workout][:difficulty]
    @workout.trainer = params[:workout][:trainer]
    @workout.user = current_user

    if @workout.save
       flash[:notice] = "Workout was updated successfully."
      redirect_to @workout
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error saving workout. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])

    if @workout.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "\"#{@workout.name}\" was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to action: :index
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error deleting the workout."
      render :show
    end
  end

  private
  def workout_params
    params.require(:workout).permit(:name, :workout_type, :teaser, :description, :video, :difficulty, :trainer, :slug, :user_id)
  end
end
```

Here is the code for the `show.html.erb` file:

```
<div class="hero-image-row">
  <div class="hero-image-outer text-center">
    <div class="hero-image-inner text-center">
      <%= image_tag 'bg-r-tirepushup.jpg', class: "hero-image",alt: "girl doing pushups on a stack of tires" %>
    </div> <!-- hero-image-inner -->
  </div> <!-- hero-image-inner -->
</div> <!-- row -->


<div class="container overlap-hero-image col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6" style="margin-top: -560px">
  <div class="row">
    <h1 class="copy-title text-center"><%= @workout.name %></h1>
    <h3 class="copy-subtitle">
      Workout Type: </strong><%= @workout.workout_type %><br><br>
      Goal: </strong><%= @workout.teaser %><br><br>
      Workout Difficulty Level: </strong><%= @workout.difficulty %>
    </h3>
    <div class="text-center">
      <%= link_to "Back to Your Workouts", workouts_path %><br>
      <%# if current_user.admin? %>
         <%= link_to 'Edit Workout', edit_workout_path(@workout) %> |
         <%= link_to 'Delete Workout', workout_path(@workout), method: :delete %><br>
         <%= link_to 'Add/Edit Exercises', workout_exercises_path(@workout, @exercise) %>
      <%# end %>
    </div> <!-- text-center -->
  </div> <!-- row -->
</div> <!-- container overlap-hero-image -->




  <% if flash[:notice] %>
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <%= flash[:notice] %>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="height: 40px"></div>
<% elsif flash.now[:alert] %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <%= flash.now[:alert] %>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="height: 40px"></div>
<% elsif flash[:alert] %>
  <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <%= flash[:alert] %>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="height: 40px"></div>
<% end %>



<div class="container col-sm-10 col-sm-push-1">
  <div class="opaque-card md-well well">
    <h1>The Workout</h1>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 25px"><strong>Description: </strong><%= @workout.description %></p>
    <iframe width="100%" height="450" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<%= @workout.video %>?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <h2>Report Your Scores</h2>
      <% if @workout.exercises.count == 0 %>
        <p>Looks like you get a freebie for this one!  No score report today.  Rest up and drink some water.  It ain't always that easy...</p>
      <% else %>
        <% @workout.exercises.each do |exercise| %>
          <%= render 'reports/form', report: @report, exercise: exercise %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>

      <h2>Your Previous Results</h2>
        <% @workout.exercises.each do |exercise| %>
          <h5><%= exercise.name %></h5>
          <%= render exercise.reports, report: @report, exercise: exercise %>
        <% end %>
    </div> <!-- container -->
  </div> <!-- md well -->
```

And here is the `reports/form` it references:

```
<%# if @exercise.reports.last != nil && @exercise.report.last.created_at < ( DateTime.now - (3/24.0)) %>

<%= form_for report,
  :url => { :controller => "reports",
  :action => :create,
  :workout_id => @workout.id,
  :exercise_id => exercise.id } do |f| %>
<div class="row">
    <h5><strong><%= exercise.name %></strong></h5>
        <% if exercise.needs_reps? %>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
            <%= f.label :reps %>
            <%= f.number_field :reps, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
        <% if exercise.needs_seconds? %>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
            <%= f.label :seconds%>
            <%= f.number_field :seconds, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
        <% if exercise.needs_weight? %>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
            <%= f.label :weight %>
            <%= f.number_field :weight, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
  <div class="col-xs-3"><%= f.submit "Record Results", class: 'btn btn-primary' %></div>
</div> <!-- row -->
<% end %>

<%# end %>
```

My routes are as follows:

```
resources :workouts do
  resources :exercises
end

resources :exercises, only: []  do
  resources :reports
end
```

Again, everything works perfectly in my `localhost`. I only get the error message when I deploy to Heroku. It doesn't reject the push (i.e. it says the deploy is successful), but when I try to access the page is when I get the `We're sorry, but something went wrong.` error.  Does anyone have any experience with this problem? If at all possible I would like to avoid resetting my database completely because I have already put information in other tables, but I am amenable to dropping and reloading the `workouts` data table if that is necessary.

Comment: From the first glance, can it be that in Heroku database you don't have any `Workout` records? If so, then `@most_recent_workout` would return `nil` and hence the error.

Comment: That is possible, but how do I create any if I can't access it to do so?

Comment: You can include in the seeds. http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html

Comment: Won't this seed my development db on `localhost` not Heroku's production db?

Comment: Well, you're going to deploy to heroku, right? The seeds usually get run as part of the deploy script.

Comment: Ahh.  Okay.  And they won't mess with any of my other tables, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113985/discussion-between-petr-gazarov-and-liz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `@most_recent_workout` returns `nil` and Rails path helper `workout_path` throws an error because it expects an id or model argument but gets `nil`.

You likely don't have any `Workout` records in your production database (Heroku), causing @most_recent_workout to return `nil`.

The quickest way to fix, open Heroku rails console and manually create the `Workout`.

```
$ heroku login
$ heroku run rails console

pry(main)> Workout.create(...)
```

A good practice is to include seeds with your deploys for anything that your code depends on.